# Issue with reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

At least for me it says I have the same reputation on both the main Apple.SE site and meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's by design: Upvotes and downvotes have no effect on your reputation in the per site metas (everything but MSO).

> **Reputation is always inherited from the parent site.** You cannot gain or lose reputation* on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the rep graph and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta.

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/ for more information, also check out a related question on MSU: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1255/how-does-the-reputation-on-parent-and-on-meta-site-work

Comment: That seems odd but I'll go for that.